# Issue with Z ordering of images inside a layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a set of images inside a horizontal scroll view. Each image is overlapped on the adjacent images on both the edges. When I click on a particular image, that should come over on top of the other images on both the edges. That works fine using,

```
tab[id].bringToFront();
tabParent.invalidate();
```

Inside my layout, I have a case to hide the whole horizontal scroll view and bringing it back. I have a problem here. When it comes back, the order of the images are realigned.

Say, I have 5 images and current id = 2. Then order is like

```
3 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 2
```

after the view comes back from View.GONE mode. How can I handle this case properly with bringToFront() and invalidate() methods?

Comment: is your problem solved, using arraylist for order array will be best option in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

your only option is bringtofront function so i suggest you this workaround

make a array of the imageviews or other view like this

```
View[] views=new View[]{anyview,imageview,otherview,linearlayout,imageview2};//add any type of view
```

now as you know that the new order should be
3 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 2

the you can make a array or arraylist of this order
suppose `int[] order=new int[]{3,4,5,1,2};`
 then use "for" loop

```
for(int i=0;i<order.length;i++)
{
  views[order[i]].bringToFront();
}
```